# How to get front end to see .env contents?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on an app that has client side and server side hosted on two seperate heroku deployments. When I hard code the url in the axios call from the front end to the back end it works in the production environment:

auth.js file:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://url.herokuapp.com/'

function Auth() {
    axios.get(baseUrl + 'api/user', test)
```

But if I add the following to the .env file and change the code as below it doesn't work:

auth.js file:

```
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL || '/'

function Auth() {
    axios.get(baseUrl + 'api/user', test)
```

.env file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    REACT_APP_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3001/"
} else {
    REACT_APP_SERVER_URL = "https://url.herokuapp.com/"
}
```

I've tried adding and installing dotenv to a route server.js file on the front end but now luck

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

.env file is not a js file that you can write code. It is just plain text.

So you can use it like:

.env

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=http://example.com
NODE_ENV=production
```

Then you can read it.

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL );
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL || '/'
axios.get(baseUrl + 'api/user', test)
```

In this documentation, you can find how to apply env variables via heroku config vars. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: In the .env file how do alter REACT_APP_SERVER_URL based on if the it's in development or production?

Comment: Don't put .env file on your build and change your heroku env parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "change your heroku end parameters"?

Comment: @DanielS. Read this documentation devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars